# How to customize MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` (for an iOS 4 app) in order to play some remote mp3 files. When I add the view like that:

```
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 20)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

I get the following:

[image]

Is it possible to customize this view? I would like to tint the color, or even add custom controls, a different progress bar etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to customize the view, but whats possible for sure is that you can build your own class and use the properties, instance methods and notifications of the `MPMoviePlayerController` to control it with your own created GUI.
Maybe the best idea is to extent the `MPMoviePlayerController` class and override it's view property.

Comment: And what about the progress view? Shall I update the GUI every one second based on the current playback time??

Comment: For a nice example have a look at http://digitaldj.net/ and https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer. According to the description of the project: "A streaming audio player class (AudioStreamer) for Mac OS X and iPhone."

Answer (score 5):

See a sample of a custom view/viewController combo in [Pragmatic iPad Programming](http://pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming). Check the source code for chapter 8 (free download from that page).